# Android vertically align listview elments on longest

Tags: android, listview, tablerow

I have created this layout for a listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_row"
    android:background="@color/icon_and_name_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TableRow>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <com.Wonderland.graphicObjects.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/Alice_Title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

It's composed from a icon on the left and a text on the right. The text is justified on the left, and all the elements of the listview are vertically aligned.

The client wants that the row with longest text horizontally centered (both icon and text) and all the other rows must be aligned with this one.

I tried to inflate the rows in the ArrayAdapter on initialization to find out which is the longest, but I get always 0.

How can I meet my client's need?

Comment: If you can't argue with your customer, then the only way to do what he asks is making a custom component.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem setting a custom margin on the left of the image for every row.

The new row xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_row"
    android:background="@color/icon_and_name_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />


    <com.Wonderland.graphicObjects.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@color/Alice_Title"
                android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="40px" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Now all the images have the same width, so it's more easy to align every element.

In the custom ArrayAdapter I added this code to calculate the left margin

```
/**
 * Method to calculate the left margin of the object to center the longest
 */
private void calculateLeftMargin() {

    // reset the left margin
    marginLeft = 0;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    // lenght of the screen
    int width = size.x;
    int height = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_row);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    View row = inflateRow(linearLayout);

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);

    // max length of the object
    int maxLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {

        Character c = getItem(i);

        icon.setImageDrawable(c.getDrawableImage(context));
        name.setText(c.getName());

        row.measure(width, height);

        int max = icon.getMeasuredWidth() + name.getMeasuredWidth();

        if (maxLength < max)
            maxLength = max;
    }

    // margin left to center the longest object
    marginLeft = (width - maxLength) / 2;
}
```

I create a custom LinearLayout object, inflate in this the resource of the arrayAdapter and force Android to calculate the measurements through **row.measure(width, height);**. Of all the widths I keep the longest to calculate the margin, horizontally centering the longest row.

In the **getView** method, above the *return row* I put this code:

```
    // Update the margin left of every row to align to the longest object
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(holder.icon.getLayoutParams());
    params.setMargins(marginLeft, 0, 0, 0);
    holder.icon.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This code updates the margin left of every image to the value found before, aligning all the rows.